# Problema com o Segmention fault

Tags: c, default

Estava estudando um pouco, sou bem iniciante em programação, e me deparei com um erro, o `segmention default`, deixarei abaixo meu código, e se for possível, alguém consiga desvendar o motivo pelo qual estou recebendo esse erro.

OBS: O erro vem logo após digito a idade.

```
//Leitura de arquivo
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  FILE *arq;

  arq = fopen("arq.txt", "a");

  if(arq == NULL) {
    printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo.");
    return 0;
  } else {

  struct fichaAluno {
    char nome[50];
    char disciplina[50];
    int idade;
    float primNota;
    float segNota;
  };

      struct fichaAluno aluno;

      printf("\t====================================================");
      printf("\n\t\t\tCADASTRO DE ALUNO\n");
      printf("\t====================================================");
      printf("\n\n\t\t\tNOME: ");
      fgets(aluno.nome, 50, stdin);
      fprintf(arq, "%s", aluno.nome);

      printf("\n\t\t\tDISCIPLINA: ");
      fgets(aluno.disciplina, 50, stdin);
      fprintf(arq, "%s", aluno.disciplina);

      printf("\n\t\t\tIDADE: ");
      scanf("%d", aluno.idade);
      fprintf(arq, "%d", &aluno.idade);

      printf("\n\t\t\tPRIMEIRA NOTA: ");
      scanf("%f", aluno.primNota);
      fprintf(arq, "%f", &aluno.primNota);

      printf("\n\t\t\tSEGUNDA NOTA: ");
      scanf("%f", &aluno.segNota);
      fprintf(arq, "%f", &aluno.segNota);



      printf("\t====================================================");
      printf("\n\t\t\tVERIFICAR ALUNO\n");
      printf("\t====================================================");
      printf("\n\n\t\t\tNOME: %s", aluno.nome);
      printf("\n\t\t\tDISCIPLINA: %s", aluno.disciplina);
      printf("\n\t\t\tIDADE: %d\n", aluno.idade);
      printf("\n\t\t\tPRIMEIRA NOTA: %.1f\n", aluno.primNota);
      printf("\n\t\t\tSEGUNDA NOTA: %.1f\n", aluno.segNota);

      return 0;

      fclose(arq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault é um erro que ocorre quando você tenta acessar (para leitura ou escrita) um endereço na memória RAM que está reservado para outro programa (ou o próprio sistema operativo) ou que não existe.

No caso você está atribuindo valor a variável aluno.idade de forma errada. Continue usando o scanf, porém faça assim:

```
scanf("%d", &aluno.idade);
```

Você deve informar ao scanf o endereço da variável na qual deseja guardar o valor lido.

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falha_de_segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o